# Recyclerview has no LayoutManager android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement RecyclerView in my android app but it gives me error

> "RecyclerView has no Layoutmanager"

even though I initialize it in my code. My java and xml file:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".List"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try changing `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to `LinearLayoutManager`. that should fix the issue, if not can you also paste the code for your `CustomAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use signal activity for recy.... And main activity . Plz create a new xml file like list_file

Comment: I tried to use a new xml file but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that added recyclerview dependency into gradle

AndroidX

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Support library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```